# Get td textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<table border="1" id="shoppingCartTable">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src='images/products/d66506_f_b2ccat_1.jpg' height='150' width='150'/></td>
        <td>adidas Kanadia TR 6 - Grey/Black</td>
        <td id='tdqty'><input type='text' name='qty' value=1></td>
        <td id='tdprice' align='right'>$129.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src='images/products/35874_107292_79586.jpg' height='150' width='150'/></td>
        <td>PGF GENTS MARKSMAN GOLF PACK</td>
        <td id='tdqty'><input type='text' name='qty' value=2></td>
        <td id='tdprice' align='right'>$1,198.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src='images/products/dsc_8058.jpg' height='150' width='150'/></td>
        <td>Puma Hooded Sweat - Pink - Women's</td>
        <td id='tdqty'><input type='text' name='qty' value=1></td>
        <td id='tdprice' align='right'>$80.00</td>
    </tr>                                                    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Total:</td>
        <td align="right">$1,407.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="getTotalPrice()">Get Total</button>
```

I have above dynamically generated HTML table. My requirement is to get each 'qty' value in the textbox and multiply with 'price' then finally show the total at the bottom.
Can someone please help me with the javascript for this.

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. Please try to do it yourself, and post your attempt. Then we'll help you fix it and you'll learn what you did wrong.

Comment: `id` should be unique, instead of using `id`, why not change it to  `class`?

Comment: As Se0ng11 said, you can't use IDs like that. You can use the table's [*rows collection*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-table-rows), and each row's [*cells collection*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#dom-tr-cells) to get the elements you want, then parse the *textContent* or *innerHTML* as appropriate to get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post what you tried in your posts in the future, more people will be willing to help fix your code. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details on how to post an example with code. But I took a crack at what you have above and wrote the javascript quickly. It shows how it will update the total based on what you have in the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/3vc3dty4/1/

```
function getTotalPrice() {
    var subtotal = 0;
    $("#shoppingCartTable tr").each(function () {
        if( $(this).find('input[name="qty"]').length > 0 ) {
            qty = $(this).find('input[name="qty"]').val();
            price = Number($(this).find('#tdprice').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
            subtotal += qty * price;
        }
    });
    $('#total').text("$" + subtotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag and the OP hasn't indicated its use, so your answer should not depend on it (especially not without pointing out the dependency).

Comment: @RobG wat? you're trying to tell me that javascript and jQuery are 2 different things?? Blasphamy! Soon we will be able to do $(2 + 2) to get the sum.

Comment: Appreciate, because I'm new to javascript and I do not know how to start it. Future I'll add my code samples.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you refactored the HTML to make scripting easier, however the following is based on minimal changes to the markup.

If you enclose the table and button in a form and have the button pass a reference to itself to the function, you can access the input elements quite easily:

```
<form>
  <table border="1" id="shoppingCartTable">
    ...
  </table>
  <button type="button" onclick="getTotalPrice(this)">Get Total</button>
</form>
```

Once you have those, you can get the quantity and the associated price, then write it to the total cell. The following is dependent on the current DOM structure, it can be made to be much more independent of it if required (and I suspect it should be).

The following function calculates the price and puts in the the total cell. It uses a couple of helper functions, but is plain javascript and doesn't depend on a large library (and the main function is only one line longer than the offered jQuery solution).

```
// Get the text in a cell using either textContent or innerText,
// whichever is supported
function getText(el) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}

// Formats a number with comma separators
// 1234567.99 -> 1,234,567.99
function formatWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function getTotalPrice(el) {
  var qtys = el.form.qty;
  var total = 0;
  var cell, inp, price, row;
  for (var i=0, iLen=qtys.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    inp = qtys[i];
    cell = inp.parentNode;
    total += +getText(cell.parentNode.cells[cell.cellIndex + 1]).replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'') * inp.value;
  }
  row = cell.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.rows[row.rowIndex + 1].cells[1].innerHTML = '$' + formatWithCommas(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

This isn't very robust as it assumes the user inputs valid values for quantity and the DOM structure doesn't change. However, you can add as many extra rows as you wish provided they maintain the same structure.